# Assigning stdin to file also assigns stdout to that file

Tags: bash, exec, stdout, stdin

I executed the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/env bash
exec 0<log
```

My understanding is that it permanently reassigns the stdin for this bash process to the log file. So, when I ran

```
ls > log
```

I expected that I was passing "ls" to stdin. Since I have not reassigned stdout, I was also expecting to see the result of the "ls" command in the terminal (where I normally see stdout). However, I saw the output of "ls" in the log file. Why is stdout in the log file and not the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` writes to whatever file it is given for standard output. Without a redirection, that is whatever file it inherits from its parent (your script). With the redirection, you are explicitly providing the file `log` for standard output.

This is independent of whatever else the file `log` might be used for.